# Does the following characterization of the elements of $\mathscr P$($\omega$) fail for ITTM's?

Tags: computability-theory, constructibility, infinite-time-computability, infinite-time-turing-machine

Hartley Rogers Jr., on pg. 120 of his text, *Theory of Recursive Functions and Effective Computability*, presents and discusses the following characterization of the sets in $\mathscr P(\omega)$:

$\mathscr B_{0}$ = {$A$| $A$ is recursively enumerable}

$\mathscr B_{1}$ = {$A$| $A$ is immune}

$\mathscr B_{2}$ = {$A$| $A$ is not recursively enumerable and $A$ is the union of an infinite recursively enumerable set and an immune set}

$\mathscr B_{3}$ = {$A$| ($\forall $recursively enumerable $B$) [$B$ $\subset$ $A$ $\Rightarrow$ ($\exists$ recursively enumerable $C$)
[$C$ $\subset$ $A$ & $C$ infinite & $C$ $\cap$ $B$ = $\emptyset$]] where no uniform effective method exists for finding an r.e. index for such a $C$ from an r.e. index for $B$}

$\mathscr B_{4}$ = {$A$| $A$ is productive}

then states

> It is trivial to show (Exercise 8-34) that this classification is mutually exclusive and exhaustive [for $\mathscr P$($\omega$)--my comment].  Classes $\mathscr B_{1}$ to $\mathscr B_{4}$ may be viewed as regions along a spectrum of increasing "richness" in the possession of recursively enumerable subsets.

Can this "mutually exclusive and exhaustive" classification of the members of $\mathscr P$($\omega$) be shown to fail if one replaces the notion of "Turing machine" implicit in the definition of this classification with "ITTM", and if this classification does, in fact, hold for ITTM's, in which of these classes can one find "lost melodies"?

Comment: Are you certain you've transcribed this correctly?  As written, I'm fairly sure a 1-generic falls into both $B_1$ and $B_3$.

Comment: Perhaps it's supposed to be $C\cap B =^* \emptyset$?

Comment: @DanTuretsky:  Thanks.  Fixed.

Comment: @DanTuretsky: Did adding $C$ $\subset$ $A$ to $\mathscr B_{3}$ fix the problem?  That would have been the correct transcription so I just wanted to check.

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin Some thoughts about $\mathscr B_{0}$. One question is that, for this question, how would  one define the analogue of r.e. or c.e. sets in the case of ITTMs. For example, one definition of c.e. set is that for any such set $A$ we must be able to find a program computing a partial computable function $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that the function $f$ halts precisely on those inputs $a$ for which $a \in A$. And for the other inputs $a$ where $a \notin A$, the program computing $f$ never halts.

Comment: Suppose we use this specific definition for $\mathscr B_{0}$ and write the resulting collection of sets as "ITTM c.e. sets". Then it seems to me that a simple argument would show that $\mathscr B_{0} \subseteq E$, where $E$ is collection of (ITTM) eventually writeable sets (each member of $E$ is some subset of $\mathbb{N}$). With a bit more work, it seems that one can show that $\mathscr B_{0} \subset E$.

Comment: Also, when I wrote "eventually writeable sets", I just meant "eventually writeable reals" treated as functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\{0,1\}$ and then converted to subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ (in the obvious way).

Comment: @SSequence:  Interesting.  Question 1:  Consider $K$ = {$x$| $x$ $\in$ $W_{x}$} in classical recursion theory and compare it with the halting problem for ITTMs, i.e., $H$ = {($p$, $x$)| $p$ halts on $x$}.  It is known that $H$ is semidecidable  but not decidable and that $\bar K$ is productive ($K$ is, of course, semidecidable).  Is $\bar H$ productive in a manner analogous to $\bar K$?  Question 2:  how are eventually writable reals related to accidently writable reals?  I ask simply because your "thoughts about $\mathscr  B_{0}$" seem very plausible.

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin Regarding (Q2), the (ITTM) eventually writeable reals are strict subset of (ITTM) accidentally writeable reals. For (Q1), I don't have much idea ...... in part because I am not familiar (haven't studied) with the notions mentioned in the other sets $\mathscr{B_1}$ to $\mathscr{B_4}$.

Comment: @SSequence:  Looking through the Hamkins/Lewis paper I find two statements of interest to me--1) "Thus, it is clear that every writable real is eventually writable, and every eventually writable real is accidently writable" (pg. 21), and 2) "An ordinal will be regarded as writable when there is a writable real coding that ordinal.  We will show later that that such ordinals extend far beyond the recursive ordinals.  Indeed, their supremum is recursively inaccessible."  Is this supremum (since the set of all accidently writable ordinals via their codes is a set of reals) itself an accidently

Comment: (cont.) writable ordinal?  As you can see this is related to your notion that $\mathscr B_{0}$ $\subseteq$ $E$.

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin The quoted part seems to be referring to supremum of writeable ordinals. Yes, the supremum itself will be eventually writeable (and hence also accidentally writeable).

Comment: @SSequence: Thanks, very helpful.  According to the Hamkins/Lewis Implication Theorem (6.15 1, 2, 3 in their paper [pg. 42]), $\mathscr B_{0}$ $\subseteq$ $E$ (with the realization that ITTMs can also compute what ordinary Turing machines can compute by restricting "to the case of finite input and time" (pg. 6 of their paper). So what is one to make of the semi-decidability of reals in lieu of their (Hamkins' and Lewis') Indescribability Theorem (8.3. pg. 50), Corollary 8.6 (pg. 53). and their argument that the accidently writable but not eventually writable real $\zeta$ (pp, 53-54 of their

Comment: (cont.) paper) "is recursively inaccessible, and indescribable, and so on' just as before...so $\zeta$ is indescribable by eventually semi-decidable properties"?

Comment: Firstly about $\mathscr{B_0}$, I don't know whether the def. of semi-decidable in the paper matches with what I described in the 
initial comments. In the case that the definitions do match, then it seems $\mathscr{B_0} \subset E$ should hold (given the "implication theorem" you referred also says that the implications are not reversible). Now denoting $\lambda$, $\zeta$, $\Sigma$ for sup of writeable, eventually writeable, accidentally writeable respectively ..... intuitively understanding recursive inaccessibility (for $\lambda$, $\zeta$) is not that difficult **after** .....

Comment: certain preliminary results are established (related to ITTMs). But nevertheless, it is too long for comments. In one sentence, one can use a program that systematically lists codes for all accidentally writeable ordinals (say, in increasing order), and use it to show that if $\lambda$ and $\zeta$ were not recursively inaccessible then they would be writeable and eventually writeable respectively (violating their def.). For somewhat similar reasons, there is no OTM program that clocks in the interval $[\lambda,\Sigma)$.

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin For an exposition on ITTMs, one I found number of years ago "Infinite time computations and infinite algorithms -- Anton Broberg". I didn't get the chance to read it, but probably it would be useful if I had read/understood portions of it, since my knowledge on ITTMs is quite sketchy on number of points (even after ignoring that I don't understand base definitions of $\alpha$-computation or $L_\alpha$ etc.). Nevertheless, the exposition looks reasonably good.

Comment: To avoid confusion, in the second last comment, I assumed that one has already shown that $\lambda$, $\zeta$ must be limit of admissibles and the task remaining is to show that they are recursively inaccessible (perhaps not the ideal order). One could probably change the order and (i) first show that $\lambda$, $\zeta$  are admissible ..... and then show that (ii) they are recursively inaccessible.

Comment: @SSequence:  I have found Anton Broberg's Masters essay in logic as a pdf file and have downloaded it on my smartphone and in hard copy and find it very helpful!  Thank you SSequence!  As regards the "implication theorem", it does in fact say, "and none of these implications is reversible" (see pg. 42 Theorem 6.15 (5)) so I would say $\mathscr B_{0}$ $\subset$ $E$.  What would you say would be a counterexample to this?

Comment: It seems that the paper uses diagonalization. We can turn all (output) bits to $1$. Simulate all  ITTM programs (domain $\mathbb{N}$). Whenever $\phi_e(e)$ halts, turn the corresponding (output) bit to $0$. We will get the diagonalized set by the time $\lambda$. One other (very) indirect way would be to first eventually write $\lambda$ and then use simulation of all ITTM programs (domain $\mathbb{N}$) to determine the state of their output sequence at $\lambda$. We will have access to all the elements of $\mathscr{B_0}$. Now just $sup^{+}$ of all the codes of ordinals in $\mathscr{B_0}$.

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin The above indirect method is what I had in mind initially. But now it seems to me that one can get some more insight using a more direct (and somewhat more involved) method. I am somewhat tentative on this (and hopefully not making a mistake), but it seems that $\mathscr{B_0}$ can't contain a code for $\lambda$ (which isn't true for $E$, and that's why $\zeta>\lambda$). The reasoning I have in mind (if it works), is that if $\mathscr{B_0}$ contained a code for $\lambda$ then $\lambda$ would be writeable (which isn't true).

Comment: @SSequence:  Why would one expect $\mathscr B_{0}$ = {$A$| $A$ is recursively enumerable} to contain a code for $\lambda$?  That would seem to mean that $\lambda$ is a recursively enumerable set and then definitely writable.  Also, how does that relate to the possibility that $B_{0}$ $\subset$ $E$?  It should be noted that {$x$| $\varphi_{x}$ not total} and {$x$| $\varphi_{x}$ total} are both non-recursively enumerable sets (these sets are called productive sets so would be in $\mathscr B_{4}$) so both are not writable by a recursive function (though both are probably writable and probably

Comment: (cont.) decidable by an ITTM).

Comment: Note also that Rogers states in his book on pg. 21 that $\varphi_{x}$ is the function of one variable determined by the set of TM instructions $P_{x}$ so it is a recursive function.

Comment: I am confused. Your posts seem to be talking about "ordinary TMs", yet the question about (possible) generalization of the corresponding notions to "ITTMs". See my first two comments at the top. Also, for example, in the version of the (quoted) paper that I noticed that the following is written just before the "implication theorem": "we regard a real as semi-decidable when there is a supertask algorithm which gives the affirmative answers to queries about the digits of the real." So, in these comments, we are talking about some specific set which ..... (continued)

Comment: we call "set of (infinite-time) semi-decidable reals" and denote as $\mathscr{B_0}$. Note that we have $\mathscr{B_0} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. But it is important to avoid confusion. For example, in version of paper I have, in the early pages the notion of (partial) ITTM computable function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is defined. And then the paper defines a notion for some arbitrary set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ as a "(infinite-time) semi-decidable set". So, to avoid ambiguity, it is important to be clear about what we are talking about. Finally, in case it wasn't clear (cont.)

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin from context, by code for $\lambda$, I meant a well-order (of $\mathbb{N}$) with order-type $\lambda$. There is a general tendency for comments here to get confusing when the discussion get long because of: (1) Limit of comment length. (2) (almost) no time window for modification. (3) Cascading of a mistake in one comment can happen easily because of lack of comments being given a marker such as a number (so it becomes hard to refer to the specific comment for the poster to point to that mistake). So I think I will leave it here. It was an interesting discussion.

Comment: The sort of generalization I meant includes classical (ordinary) recursion theory by the definition of ITTM given by Hamkins and Lewis on the first page of their preprint: "Our model is simple:  we simply extend the Turing machine concept into transfinite ordinal time.  The resulting machines can perform infinitely many steps of computation, and go on to more computation after that.  But mechanically they work just like Turing machines.  In particular, they have the usual Turing machine hardware; there is the same smooth infinite paper tape and the same mechanical head moving back and forth

Comment: (cont.) according to a finite algorithm, with finitely many states [i.e. an ordinary Turing machine running in transfinite ordinal time--my comment].  What is new is the definition of the behavior of the machine at limit ordinal times [if you are going to have an ordinary Turing machine run in transfinite ordinal time you obviously have to account for that sort of behavior--Hamkins and Lewis gave a 'natural' definition of such behavior with very interesting consequences--my comment]."  Why these ITTM's are able to perform according to the strictures of classical (ordinary) recursion theory is

Comment: (cont.) given by Hamkins and Lewis in the following comment found on pg. 6 of their preprint:  "Thus, restricting to the case of finite input and time, a function $f$:  $2^{{\lt} {\omega}}$ $\rightarrow$ $2^{{\lt}{\omega}}$

Comment: (cont.) is $\omega$-computable exactly when it is computable in the Turing machine sense."  This is the context in which a proper answer to my question should be given.

Comment: @SSequence:  Thank you for your input.  It has been very helpful.